# Vue.js array in object from db is undefined, even though the values appear in console

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to get data from db and show it on the screen. I get the data using axios, i got the response successfully. So, i use `forEach` to get arrays inside the data.

```
 mounted(){
    axios.get('/api/tree').then(Response => {
                var datas =Response.data.trees

                datas.forEach(function(data){
                    var tree = data.tree
                    console.log(tree)
                    console.log(tree.nodes)
                })
    })

}
```

the data is as below.

```
{
    'id' : "aeENkvQdx",
    'tree': {  
         'nodes' : [{ 'node_id': 0, 'text': 'test'}, .....],
         'edges' : [{ 'node_id': 0, 'text': 'test'}, .....]
     }

}
```

so, when i print `console.log(tree)` it's working fine. It shows `{ 'nodes' : [...,..,], 'edges: [...,...,...]}`.
However, when i print `console.log(tree.nodes)` or `console.log(tree.edges)`, then it shows an error saying
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodes')` or 'edges', even though it prints the values of nodes or edges array in the console.
I have no idea why it only causes error when i try to access nodes or edges, and how to solve this issue...

Comment: I think you need to do `console.log(tree.tree.nodes);` - It usually makes it clearer when your parent variable is not name of one of your properties, and you end up getting clearer errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because in some of the `data` objects, `tree` property is missing. Hence, when you trying to access `nodes` or `edges` objects it is giving you the below error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodes')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edges')

You can resolve this by using [`Optional Chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.

```
console.log(tree?.nodes)
console.log(tree?.edges)
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
const datas = [{
  'id' : "aeENkvQdx",
  'tree': {  
    'nodes' : [{ 'node_id': 0, 'text': 'test'}],
    'edges' : [{ 'node_id': 0, 'text': 'test'}]
  }

}, {
  'id' : "aeENkdYJh"
}];

datas.forEach(function(data) {
  var tree = data.tree;
  console.log(tree);
  console.log(tree?.nodes);
});
```